# How do I protect my ceiling from soot from my wood burning stove?

Tags: paint, stove, woodstove, smoke

I have a ~1920s wood-burning farmhouse cook stove in my kitchen which we use regularly. Obviously, smoke and soot builds up on the vaulted ceiling around the stove.

I'm looking some type of paint or ideas for good materials that are easier to clean smoke/soot off of.

Comment: How about a vent hood to draw the dirty air out of the house? If not that, a _very_ high gloss paint (will be the smoothest paint finish), or stainless steel to protect the impacted areas.

Comment: What is the material on your existing ceiling? Wood? Drywall? Textured/popcorn drywall? What is your budget?   I agree with Freeman that stainless steel would be a good choice. Tempered glass may be another.

Comment: Proper operation of inlet air and flue damper should keep smoke to a minimum.

Comment: @peinal The ceiling is just standard drywall and the brick wall/chimney behind the stove.